# Asyncio run Task conditional of another Task

Tags: python, graphql, python-asyncio

I want to run a task infinitely. Basically, the script needs to do the following:

- check each week if there is a match
- sleep until the match starts
- create a connection with the websocket
- check the status of a match using a subscription query
- depending on the status of the match run another subscription and log the output
- close the websocket connection at some point and start all over again.

I wrote the following script for it:

```
import asyncio
from gql import Client
from gql.transport.websockets import WebsocketsTransport


async def execute_subscription1(session):
    async for response in session.subscribe(subscription1):
        if response['status'] == 'in progress':
            task_2 = asyncio.create_task(execute_subscription2(session))
            asyncio.run(task_2)

        elif response['status'] == 'complete':
            # task_1 is completed
            return None

        else:
            # status is suspended / starting soon / waiting etc
            try:
                task_2.cancel()
            except (asyncio.CancelledError, asyncio.InvalidStateError):
                pass


async def execute_subscription2(session):
    async for response in session.subscribe(subscription2):
        print(response)


async def graphql_connection():
    transport = WebsocketsTransport(url="wss://YOUR_URL")
    client = Client(transport=transport, fetch_schema_from_transport=False)

    async with client as session:
        task_1 = asyncio.create_task(execute_subscription1(session))

        await task_1

async def watch(game):
    seconds_until_game = get_time_until_game()
    await asyncio.sleep(seconds_until_game)
    await graphql_connection()


async def watch_always() -> None:
    while True:
        game = get_upcoming_game()
        asyncio.run(watch(game))


loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(watch_always())
```

I expect that I will receive `response` from `session.subscribe(subscription1)` every minute. I expect that a change in the match status will only occur every 10 minutes.

So, I only want to launch `task_2` the first time `response['status'] == 'in progress'` or the first time `response['status'] == 'in progress'` after being earlier cancelled. How can I achieve this?
In addition, I read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-exceptions.html) of the errors, but I couldn't conclude whether `(asyncio.CancelledError, asyncio.InvalidStateError)` is called when a non-existent task is cancelled.

Please advice

Answer (score 1):

To launch task_2 only the first time response['status'] == 'in progress' or the first time response['status'] == 'in progress' after being earlier cancelled, you can use a boolean flag to keep track of whether task_2 has already been launched for the current status. For example, you can add a variable task_2_launched to execute_subscription1() and set it to False initially. Then, when response['status'] == 'in progress', you can check if task_2_launched is False, launch task_2, and set task_2_launched to True. If task_2_launched is already True, you can skip launching task_2.

Regarding the second question, asyncio.CancelledError is raised when a task is cancelled, either by calling task.cancel() or when a task is cancelled due to an exception or a timeout. asyncio.InvalidStateError is raised when an operation is performed on a closed or cancelled event loop, so it's not directly related to cancelling tasks. In your case, you can catch asyncio.CancelledError when cancelling task_2, but you don't need to catch asyncio.InvalidStateError because it's not relevant to your code.

Here's an updated version of your code that implements the task_2_launched flag and catches asyncio.CancelledError when cancelling task_2:

```
import asyncio
from gql import Client
from gql.transport.websockets import WebsocketsTransport

async def execute_subscription1(session):
    task_2_launched = False
    async for response in session.subscribe(subscription1):
        if response['status'] == 'in progress':
            if not task_2_launched:
                task_2_launched = True
                task_2 = asyncio.create_task(execute_subscription2(session))
        elif response['status'] == 'complete':
            # task_1 is completed
            return None
        else:
            # status is suspended / starting soon / waiting etc
            if task_2_launched:
                try:
                    task_2.cancel()
                except asyncio.CancelledError:
                    pass
                task_2_launched = False

async def execute_subscription2(session):
    async for response in session.subscribe(subscription2):
        print(response)

async def graphql_connection():
    transport = WebsocketsTransport(url="wss://YOUR_URL")
    client = Client(transport=transport, fetch_schema_from_transport=False)
    async with client as session:
        task_1 = asyncio.create_task(execute_subscription1(session))
        await task_1

async def watch(game):
    seconds_until_game = get_time_until_game()
    await asyncio.sleep(seconds_until_game)
    await graphql_connection()

async def watch_always() -> None:
    while True:
        game = get_upcoming_game()
        await watch(game)

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(watch_always())
```

> Note that I removed the asyncio.run() calls inside the functions
> because asyncio.run() should only be called once in the main program
> to start the event loop. Also, I simplified the watch() function to
> just call graphql_connection() directly since get_time_until_game()
> and get_upcoming_game() are not defined in the code snippet.